# How can I hide elements with an attribute that doesn't match an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with various links in that I want to search through using an input field.

```
<form>
    <input id="search">
</form>
<ul>
    <li data-name="one"></li>
    <li data-name="two"></li>
    <li data-name="ozone"></li>
</ul>
```

how can I use jquerys keyup event to hide the li with data-name "two" when I type "on" or various other word snippets into the input field?

search: "two"

- two

search: "o"

- one
- two
- ozone

search: "on"

- one
- ozone

Here's a JSFiddle for what I have so far, but it only works by matching from the start of the word, not inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssDG5/

Comment: It seems that contrary to the title, you wish to hide elements with an attribute value that do *not* match an input value. Moreover, the task is underspecified and really a task assignment rather than a question suitable for SO. You should specify what you want, show what you have tried, and explain how it fails.

Comment: I've editted to question to try and clear things up and also included a jsfiddle link for what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function()
{
    var val = this.value;

    if (val)
        $('ul > li:not([data-name*="' + val + '"])').hide();
    else
        $('ul > li').show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVecz/)

Comment: Thanks, I was completely unaware that * would work in that and didn't think to try it. I was only familiar with ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to loop through all li's and hide them based on the input value:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    $("li").each(function(index, li) {
        if ($(li).data("data-name").indexOf($("#search").val()) < 0) {
            $(li).hide();
        }
    });
});
```